# Psycopg-2 Not installing on Mac

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Am trying to download and run psycopg2 in an effort to make a connection with a Postgresql DB.

Some info:

- Mac OSX
- Flask App
- Postgresql==12.3
- python==3.7

Keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:/Users/usr/Desktop/flagging/venv/bin/python3.7 
-u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = 
'"'"'/private/var/folders/dp/vtrw_dl53tq6_w3c3v0vnd3m0000gn/T/pip-install- 
14efe1an/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; 
__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/dp/vtrw_dl53tq6_w3c3v0vnd3m0000gn/T/pip-install- 
14efe1an/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open). 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 
/private/var/folders/dp/vtrw_dl53tq6_w3c3v0vnd3m0000gn/T/pip-record-u6rqov3u/install- 
record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 
/Users/usr/Desktop/flagging/venv/include/site/python3.7/psycopg2 Check the logs for full 
  command output.
```

Database.py file:

```
import os
import psycopg2

DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']

conn = psycopg2.connect(database=DATABASE_URL, user="postgres", host="localhost", password="password", port=5432)

conn.close()
```

Project Structure:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── flagging_site
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── blueprints
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── cyanobacteria.py
│   │   └── flagging.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── _store
│   │   │   ├── hobolink.pickle
│   │   │   ├── refresh.py
│   │   │   └── usgs.pickle
│   │   ├── database.py
│   │   ├── hobolink.py
│   │   ├── keys.py
│   │   ├── model.py
│   │   ├── task_queue.py
│   │   └── usgs.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │   ├── CRWA_banner_main.jpg
│   │   │   ├── blue_flag.jpg
│   │   │   ├── red_flag.jpg
│   │   │   └── yellow_flag.jpg
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── output_model.html
│   └── vault.zip
├── requirements.txt
├── run_heroku.py
├── run_unix_dev.sh
├── run_windows_dev.bat
├── runtime.txt
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── tests
│   ├── conftest.py
│   ├── test_data.py
│   └── test_site.py
└── ven
```

Based on comments here from people with similar issues, I have:

- Installed psycopg2-binary (successfully)
- Set environment variable: export PATH=$PATH:[path to postgresql > pg_config]*
- Switched versions of python to python3.7
- Attempted to install different version of psycopg2==2.7

*was unable to locate postgresql on my machine to complete the path

My questions are:

If I have successfully installed psycopg2-binary…. how can I import this into my database.py file to make it work? (Import psycopg2-binary and import psycopg2_binary don’t work).

Is this an issue with the Postgresql server not running? Am currently chasing this error but would like to know if I’m wasting time. Thx.

Comment: Even though the package is named psycopg2-binary, the import module is still called just psycopg2.

Comment: update: brew install libpq solved this issue. thanks for responding.